# Making Android an Database Query Ruby on Rails

Tags: android, sql, ruby-on-rails

How do I make my android application send a SQL query to a ruby on rails server holding a database about items

Answer (score 0):

You don't. SQL is for DB servers.

If you have a RoR server, it is probably expecting HTTP requests, so you need first to figure out which URL is related to the information you are looking for, get that URL content, and then parse it to get what you want.

If you have access to the server configuration, you probably want to make the DB server accessible in order to connect with it directly with JDBC, but you will have to seriously think about strongly securing it in the process.